# UIImage in-between text in UIAlertView

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, nsstring, uiimage, uialertview

How would I be able to have an image show in a UIAlertView along with some text. Apparently this isn't available in iOS7, is this true? All I want is to replace some text with an image, preferably not by using custom libraries. The NSString *formula is the one I want to replace with an image.

[image]

```
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BMI"];
    NSString *mess = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Body Mass Index, or BMI, is used by many health professionals to assess a patient's health. BMI is calculated by the formula:"];
    NSString *formula = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"                               Weight(kg)/(Height(m)*Height(m))"];

    // Combined message (mess) and Formula (formula)
    NSString *combinedMess;
    combinedMess = [mess stringByAppendingString:formula];

    NSString *mess1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Although this tool is useful in measuring a person's weight ratio, it becomes unrealiable for body builders and other extremes. BMI combined with a general indication of fitness level gives Quick Fit a clear view of the fitness level of the user."];

    // Combined message (combinedMess) and message (mess1)
    NSString *all;
    all = [combinedMess stringByAppendingString:mess1];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: title
                                                   message: all
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on iOS7 without creating your own version of an alert view. A quick google search came across this https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview which looks promising.

Per apple's documentation:

> ***Subclassing Notes***
>   The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
>   and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
>   private and must not be modified.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: I had a look at that but... Why isn't it possible in iOS7?

Comment: Indeed it is. Marking this as the solution would be appreciated if it answered your question.